# .Net web application with different api clients

Tags: .net, api, rest, design-patterns, blazor

I have a Blazor project & i need to consume several REST APIs. All of those APIs require different configuration. For example: For one of those apis i have to bypass certificate by using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback. And for another api i have to send GET request with bodypayload (which is not semantic). For another api i need JWT... and so forth.
The point is that i have different HttpClinet(s) and they require different configuration.

So the question is how do you deal with it? You have all these amazing things in .NET like dependency injection, singleton, transient, IHttpClientFactory and you can configure your api client in startup.cs or in ctor or in any other place for that matter. So what is the right approach here?

*I have a strong filling that something like strategy design pattern can be useful in this case*

Comment: If you create a Blazor WASM project with Hosting and Identity it demonstrates creating a HttpClient and associating it with a name. Then in FetchData.razor it shows how to inject a client by name.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's least favorite answer- it depends.

How do you ultimately want to interact with the APIs? Do you want an interface per API that you interact with in a standardized way? Or do you want one large interface? If the former, consider using the adapter pattern. If the latter, the facade pattern, possibly layered over top of the adapter pattern. Either way, it sounds like each API you're working with is different enough that you'll want a relatively high level of abstraction in order to standardize how you interact with them.

In terms of what things look like under the hood, there's plenty of ways you could handle it. Strategy, delegate, command, builder, simple composition and/or inheritance, more that I'm not thinking of. It really depends on your goals, how different the APIs are from one another, how many more you intend to add, etc. There are so many ways to accomplish the same goal and much of how you approach this depends on your specific context.

Comment: I think i need interface per API. All those apis are quite different and that's the reason why my code became very messy. Again, it all works just fine but i dont like the fact that code is messy. I totally agree with you on "There are so many ways to accomplish the same goal" - and that the issue here. I was hopping that someone will give me an example (github repo maybe). I would like to see how other people deal with this issue, how they interact with different apis
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I think you're going to have to post a couple of example APIs if you want examples of how to handle them. No real way to know how to accomplish what you're looking for without seeing the code.